# Fetching aggregated stats for a Group of sites

Tags: matomo

For example I have 5 sites under a group Group1. Is there a way to fetch - through API - the stats (e.g. visits) collectively for all these 5 site under Group1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply set the site group while creating the site and wrote a simple SINATRA application to fetch the stats for a particular group.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is not currently supported but there is a ticket feature request: http://dev.piwik.org/trac/ticket/2541